# CSS changing text color of element from ::after

Tags: html, css

So im trying to change the color of text when the user hovers on it but the problem is that im already using :hover to show the ::after section which im using as a background so when i use hover on the class separately it just moves the ::after section on top of the text and hides the text completely. Here is the code:

```css
.header-links {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-links::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0em;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.header-links:hover::after {
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-links:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<li class="header-links"> Tutorials </li>
<li class="header-links"> References </li>
<li class="header-links"> Exercises </li>
```

any solution to this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is setting the `z-index` of the `::after` to `-1` so it won't cover the content:

```css
.header-links {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-links::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0em;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  /* added */
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-links:hover::after {
  background: green;
}

.header-links:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<li class="header-links"> Tutorials </li>
<li class="header-links"> References </li>
<li class="header-links"> Exercises </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ::after adds a pseudo element to the DOM.  So this element is being placed over your li (covering the li).
https://martinwolf.org/before-2018/blog/2015/05/why-you-can-do-hoverafter-and-not-afterhover/

I think what you may have really wanted to do is put everything inside the hover and get rid of the hover::after

```
.header-links:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```